# How to release a winform program based on cefsharp by using VS2015 community

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I write a simple browser by using cefsharp, it worked in my computer,but I want to release it, thus other people can use it on their own computer.
I used the VS2015 community to release it, I setted up it on my computer,but when I clicked the .exe , it didn't work. Hope somebody could help me.

Besides this, I also want to make a .exe program, put all the .dll profiles into one .exe profile.

Here is the release folder[the release folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKKLW.jpg)

the .exe profile depends on many .dll profiles, I want to put all the things into one .exe profile. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: .exe and .dll is not a "profile". They are both executable modules (executable and dynamic link library). Because .NET assemblies uses same format - each modules contains native code or .NET assemby (-ies, actually multiple assemblies can be in one module).

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/55/NuGet/Readme.txt#L26

Comment: I want to know how to make a installation package by using VS2015 communiity, I tried but failed...

Comment: Search CefSharp clickonce, you need to add extra entries in your project file to copy the unmanaged resources

Comment: I used the "inno" to solve the problem.Thank you.

Comment: If you're resolved your problem then you should update your answer as a reference to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ends with 3 different modules:

1. Pure .NET assemblies
2. Mixed-mode .NET assemblies
3. Native modules

You can naturally merge only pure .NET assemblies (1) with tools like ILMerge. But you can't do same for (2) and (3).

The only way achieve similar result is package dependencies as resources and unpack them on start. But i'm strongly not recommend this way - it is always lead to problems and slow startup performance.

Just make installer.

Comment: But I don't know how to make a effective installation package.

Comment: @shiyan there is another question. read documentation. also read carefully document provided by amaitland in comments on you question.

Comment: The problem was solved by using inno.

Answer (score 0):

[set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV9f9.jpg)I tried to publish the program, and set up, when I clicked, it has no response.[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnlrF.jpg) I mean the install file not include the dependencies,like .dll.